# Django get queryset as serialized

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, if you do the following:

```
print(serializers.serialize(MyModel.objects.all()))
```

It will nicely output a JSON string in this format:

```
{
    {'pk' : 1, fields : {'fieldname1' : 'value1, 'fieldname2', 'value2'},
}
```

This is usefull when you're dealing with a 'generic' application that would work with any model, not needing to know the pk field name or the list of non-hidden non-relational field names.

For the question, how can I do this but keep it in Python, as a dictionary? I could `json.loads` the serializer output but that's just plain silly.

Closest to what I'm trying to achieve is the `.values()` QuerySet method, but it doesn't list the `pk` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `serialize` takes as its first parameter the format to serialize to. Normally this is 'json' or 'xml' but you can also use 'python', which converts to a standard Python dict.

Comment: That is good to know, the documentation really should say that though...